# Using SignalR with ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I'm attempting to use SignalR hubs in an application, but am having no luck currently. I've read through [Scott Hanselman's article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AsynchronousScalableWebApplicationsWithRealtimePersistentLongrunningConnectionsWithSignalR.aspx), and also looked at [this](http://beyondrelational.com/modules/24/syndicated/370/Posts/9623/signalr-with-mvc3-chat-app-build-asynchronous-real-time-persistant-connection-websites.aspx) blog post which shows how to implement it in MVC, basically doing the same thing. Unfortunately, I'm having no luck. On the client side, the javascript seems to work fine [apart from nothing happening] but when I place breakpoints in the code it shows that the controller is being called, not the hub code. The code I'm using is this:

```
// Client side javascript:
var hooking;
$(function() {
    // Setup SignalR
    hooking = $.connection.hooking;
    hooking.removeLead = function(ref) {
        $("lead" + ref).remove();
    };
    $.connection.hub.start();
    }
});

// Hooking.cs (placed in application root)
public class Hooking : Hub
{
    public void Submit(string jsonString)
    {
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var json = serializer.Deserialize<HookingLeadResult>(jsonString);
        Clients.removeLead(json.Ref); // Remove lead from client hooking windows
        // update lead gen
    }
}
```

When I call `hooking.submit(resultJson);` later in my code for some reason it calls the Index action of my HookingController (which is the current page). Anyone know how to correctly call the Submit function from Hooking.cs?

Comment: Looks like the blog post you reference is a dead link now.  I found the post here: http://beyondrelational.com/modules/24/syndicated/370/Posts/9623/signalr-with-mvc3-chat-app-build-asynchronous-real-time-persistant-connection-websites.aspx

Comment: Thank you, I've amended the link in the original question too now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were two issues with this - 1. For some reason an  old version of jquery.validate was causing errors, but updating it sorted this. 2. I attempted to cast to a nullable int, which I guess isn't supported. I'm sure there are more elegant ways to solve this, but I simply cast my nullable data inputs to strings and parsed them if not null

Answer (score 2):

Did you look at the network traffic in firebug or some other tool that sniffs http traffic to make sure you have no errors? It might be something to do with routing.

Also a side note, you don't need to serialize anything we do that for you. Just send objects back and forth.

When you're in an mvc app you need to include the hub script like any other static script:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/signalr/hubs")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Cheers, yeah I included the correct scripts. Firebug is showing `GET http://localhost:2823/Hooking, POST signalr/negotiate` and then when my script calls 'submit' another `GET http://localhost:2823/Hooking`. It's at this point I would've expected some call to my function defined in Hooking.cs

Comment: And all the requests are 200?

Comment: Yeah they are, actually chrome is flagging that as an error though for some reason showing 'unexpected response code: 200'

Comment: That's expected (it's the websocket request). The request for submit should look like:
Hooking/signalr/send

Comment: Yeah that was what I thought was a bit strange. The request for submit is showing as `GET http://localhost:2823/Hooking 200 OK 2650ms`

Comment: Maybe you're submitting the form and not going through signalr at all?  I'd need to see more of your code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3894/discussion-between-jordan-wallwork-and-dfowler)

Comment: Have discovered that another javascript (jquery.validate) was causing the issue. No idea why but removing it sorted the problem. However now when I try to submit() it posts as it should, but returns a 500 server error

Comment: It's all sorted now. Stupid error really, it didn't like the json I was passing it. Going to have a look at the signalr samples now to see how to pass objects back and forth! Cheers for all your help though

Comment: Actually, I have the same issue, and you will find if you F12 in chrome, even http://chatapp.apphb.com/ has the same `Unexpected response code: 200` issue. Don't know if that's normal.

Comment: Hi David, can't seem to find any help on the topic, and without opening up another Q - any command in JS to test if the broadcasted message is being sent to yourself, and if so, don't perform the particular code? I only want the js to be performed for clients who didn't issue the request in the js hub callback function :) Thanks. Perhaps I work with `id` of the hub somehow (eg. I saw `chat.id` being used for `userId`), but I'm not sure if I would send it initially through, and back through the callback, or not?

Comment: Why not open another question so others can benefit from an answer without having to dig into the comments? What you see in the other samples is the only good way to check right now.

Comment: Well, mainly because I knew you'd be alerted to this message in your SO inbox ;) selfish really. Thanks for the response, I found an alternative way with my `HttpContext.Current.User`, but if I encounter a problem with this again I will open up a question.

Comment: Don't use that, if you use web sockets the context will be null. FYI :)

Answer (score 1):

jquery.validate.js was the culprit. For some reason it was triggering GET request, and after excluding the js file, SignalR requests started triggering POST request. Perhaps I should update it as Jordan Wallwork mentioned.